# How to move a file from one folder to another through sharepoint api in python?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, python

I have a folder in sharepoint. I wanted to move a file from one folder to another.

As per documentation, my trial was like below.

```
 headers = {"Authorization" : "Barer" + Token, 
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'X-HTTP-Method': "POST",
            'X-RequestForceAuthentication': 'true'
            }

url = "https://sharepointDomain/sites/<app_name>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SourceFoldername/test.xlsx')/moveto(newurl=/sites/DestinationFolderName/Test.xlsx',flags=1)?@target=sharepointDomain"

response = request.post(url, headers = headers)
print(response)
```

And the response I get is

```
The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'moveto'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The url should be like:

```
https://sharepointDomain/sites/<app_name>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SourceFoldername/test.xlsx')/moveto(newurl='/sites/DestinationFolderName/Test.xlsx',flags=1)?@target=sharepointDomain"
```

My test code:

```
function MoveFile(){
        var oUrl =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/doc2/doc.docx')/moveto(newurl='/doc1/doc.docx',flags=1)";
        $.ajax({
            url: oUrl,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest":  $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```